# Is appToken and appId the same thing?

Tags: web, chatbot, messenger

I didn't use smooch for a while and one of the chatbots that I have stopped working in Web Messenger. I see that Whisper no longer exists, does anybody know when was that changed?

Also is appToken and appId the same thing? I am pretty sure that last time we configured appToken, and now I see just the appId.